# Определение соприкосновения объектов в Python arcade

Tags: python, ооп, arcade

Недавно начал изучать ООП и решил создать небольшую игру на Python с помощью библиотеки arcade. Я решил не использовать спрайты и их встроенные функции. Тогда у меня возникла проблема, как определить соприкасаются ли объекты. Я написал следующию функцию:

```
def get_distance(el1, el2):
    return ((el1.x - el2.x) ** 2 + (el1.y - el2.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Далле в методе update класса MyGame, я проверяю:

```
if get_distance(self.hero, bullet) < 20:
    self.bullet_list.remove(bullet)
```

Это все работает, однако если пуля попадает не точно в середину игрока, то она не исчезает. Помогите, как можно сделать определение соприкосновения объектов более точным? Какая-нибудь сложная формула?..

P.S. Так я рисую игрока:

```
def draw(self):
    arcade.draw_circle_filled(self.x, self.y, self.r, self.color)
    arcade.draw_line(self.x, self.y, self.x+45*self.dx, self.y+45*self.dy, arcade.color.BLACK, 5)
```

А это пуля:

```
def draw(self):
    arcade.draw_line(self.x, self.y, self.x+9*self.dx, self.y+9*self.dy, self.color, 5)
```

Comment: Вы этот модуль используете https://github.com/pvcraven/arcade?

Comment: ''''Именно этот

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что такое 20?

Если объект и пуля круглые, то расстояние между центрами нужно сравнивать с суммой их радиусов

```
if get_distance(self.hero, bullet) < self.r + bullet.r:
```

Для пули в виде цилиндра ("сосиски", [stadium](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stadium.html)) можно считать расстояние до центрального отрезка, но навряд ли пуля заденет объект серединой.

В общем случае, кстати, чтобы не пропустить точный момент касания, лучше этот момент рассчитать заранее, исходя из позиций и скоростей движения объектов и пуль.

Comment: А как быть с квадратными объектами? Можно, конечно, попытаться вместить их в окружность, но здесь опять будут неточности. Кстати то, что вы написали в последнем абзаце ответа, тоже довольно интересно. Мне как-раз нужно такое определение, потому что в моей игре есть также боты, которые переодически в тебя стреляют, однако они никогда не попадут, если ты все время двигаешься. Не могли ли бы вы поподробнее объяснить про такое определение? Предоставить код функции, которая будет определять, куда нужно стрелять боту? Может это и иной вопрос, чем то что я задал в заголовке, однако...

Comment: С прямоугольниками- нужно использовать [функцию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53846806/detect-rectangle-crossing-circle/53847328#53847328), которая считает расстояние от центра круга (пули) до границы прямоугольника. По упреждению при стрельбе - это действительно другой вопрос.